# Prettier vscode extension ignoring config files

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I can't get the prettier extension to use my config files. It keeps using the global settings (as defined in the config path setting in vscode). I made an example project:

https://github.com/Supperhero1/prettierTest

I set tabWidth to 1 in the .prettierrc file. When I run "npx prettier --write ." the prettier package properly formats the test.ts document to have an indentation of one, but if i save the file (I have format on save turned on) it gets formatted back to the global setting (4 spaces). I deleted all settings in the global setting but then it defaults to a tab with of two spaces. The extension seems to ignore the config file completely. A collegue has the extension and it works fine with config files.

I'm trying to figure out what could be overriding the setting, the exension description says the precedence for figuring out settings is:

```
Prettier configuration file
.editorconfig
Visual Studio Code Settings (Ignored if any other configuration is present)
```

And in the official docs, the config file resolution precedence is:

```
A "prettier" key in your package.json file.
A .prettierrc file written in JSON or YAML.
...
```

Seeing how I don't have a prettier key in my package.json file, there should be nothing that can override my .prettierrc file. I tried restarting vscode but that didn't help. Has anyone else had this issue, I'm not sure where to look to solve this problem...

Comment: Make sure the formatter your VS Code uses is Prettier, not VS Code's built-in formatter.

Comment: It's prettier, I checked that.

Comment: How exactly did you check? What is the output of the Prettier extension? (Ctrl-J to open the panel if it's not open → Output → Prettier)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware this panel existed. I set prettier as default and I formatted by using the "format document with..." option in the right click context menu and it ignores the .prettierrc file. Anyway, after seeing the output in this panel, I figured it out so thanks for that. Explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the VSCode prettier extension uses the config file in the VSCode settings over the local one, even if that config is an empty json file it then falls back to the default settings instead of the local ones (from .prettierrc). When I removed the path from Prettier: Config Path setting in VSCode it worked as expected.

I guess I expected the file in this path to be the fallback for when you don't have a local config file but, seeing how this file seems to overwrite every other setting, I guess the intended use is to set a User setting as default and then set a workspace setting for every workspace where you don't want to use the default. Or just leave the prop empty in the user settings.

Comment: This worked for me.... but only _after_ restarting VSCode.

Comment: I looked everywhere for the "Prettier: Config Path setting", there is none. Where did you find yours?

Comment: @JohnF CTRL+, (or your MacOS equivalent) to open the settings, write "config path" in the search bar and i get it under extension -> code spell checker -> prettier

Answer (score 28):

In VS Code press `Ctrl + shift + p` to open command palette then chose

*Preferences: Open Settings(JSON)* and add the line among other settings you have:

```json
  "prettier.configPath": ""
```

Save the file. Now the Prettier extension respect your local *.prettierrc* config files. Basically `Prettier: Config Path Path to the prettier configuration file` option overrides all other config files regardless of placement.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually putting the path, but after setting the path to blank, as you have, then it worked!  I guess empty probably means relative to the project root. Funky, but at least it works.

Answer (score 16):

I have encountered this problem it took me a lot of time to solve it. And finally, I found the solution to my problem similar to yours.

1. In VS Code Press open Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P)
2. Search and select this: *Format Document With...*
3. After selecting this choose *Prettier - Code formatter* to make as default formatter

Comment: legend, the only answer that worked for me. cheers to you 

Comment: It works! 
My default formatter was ***typescript*** instead of ***prettier***.  
After searching for *Format Document With..*., I clicked on *Configure default formatter* and then I selected `prettier`.
It modified my *.vscode/settings.json* file with a new rule for *javascript*:

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
 "[javascript]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
 }
```

Comment: It worked! My default formatter was "Vue Language Features (Volar)".

Answer (score 8):

For me it seems that my VSCode was already set to use its own internal parser and because of that it was being used instead (for example when doing format on save

I needed this in my `settings.json`

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Configuring the default formatter with *Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P)*  -> *Format Document With...* -> *Configure default formatter* -> *prettier*, will do the same changes to the `settings.json` automatically (you should have the file with the correct extension on focus)

Answer (score 7):

So, i got the same trouble with mistake: "Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used"

The solution is to disable this options in vscode prettier:

**Prettier: Use Editor Config** - mark it as disabled

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BueQx.png)

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. It seems that once it finds an .editorconfig, it ignores everything else. For instance, it was always setting quotes to double quotes instead of single even though it was defined as single quote on vscode user preferences and my .prettier.config.js file.

Answer (score 4):

The only way that worked with me was uninstalling and then re-installing the **Prettier - Code formatter** in VS Code.

I tried many different ways that other people recommended, but nothing worked.

FYI, my repository currently has formatting rules in `.editorconfig`, `.eslintrc.json`, `.prettierrc.html.json`, `.prettierrc.ts.json`, `.prettierrc.scss.json` locally.

Comment: Yeah, I too reinstalled prettier and everything worked like a charm. Strange things, but whatever.

Comment: Reinstalling the "Prettier - Code formatter" extension in VS Code fixed the issue for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the **editor.defaultFormatter** on the VSCode settings has worked for me,

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "prettier.useEditorConfig": false,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
  "prettier.configPath": ".prettierrc"
}
```

Comment: In my case, I had `useTabs: true`, but the tab size setting in VS Code somehow took precedence over the `tabWidth` setting for Prettier. I solved it by setting the same tab size for the VS Code workspace as set in the Prettier configuration.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was what it's listed in extension manual.

"prettier.resolveGlobalModules": true

And after this, it respects the local config

Answer (score 0):

I had to set prettier as the default formatter for a specific language. For some reason just setting it generically as the default with  `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` did not work. However,

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
```

did work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a configuration in **BOTH** a `package.json` and `.prettierrc`,
the `package.json` takes precedence!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I hadn't installed "Prettier" plugin. I actually had the "Prettier - ESLint", and some others, but the main one was missing ("Prettier - Code Formatter"). Take a look just in case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to add a `.` to the filename of my `.prettierrc.json` >.>