# Prettier Vscode extention ignoring config file

Tags: javascript, prettier

I created prettier.config.cjs:

```
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  plugins: ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"],
};
```

but when I am using single quote the prettier change it into double quote so it is ignoring my configs. What's wierd is that the plugin *does* work that's mean the problem is not with that tailwind plugin

How do I fix it?

edit:my default formatter is prettier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prettier vscode extension ignoring config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66781267/prettier-vscode-extension-ignoring-config-files)

Comment: should be the `.editorconfig` in your root. Try `[*.ts]` `quote_type = single`.

Comment: No it doesn't.I tried as in that question. Naveen J where can I find it?

Comment: After I reloaded my VScode it works. does it should be like that or does it supposed to work instantly

Answer (score -1):

You should install the NPM Package `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` then reload/reopen vscode.

Comment: I have and the talwind plugin works but the ```singleQuote:true``` doesn't and the prrettier change it to double quote

Comment: It works on my end. Seems to be a problem on your end.